# WinRT Settings Charm. Elements overlayed by on screen keyboard

Tags: user-interface, windows-8, client, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm developing for Windows 8 (WInRT) and have problem with settings charm. Settings popup is based on Microsoft SDK settings charm. Settings panel is Popup. Content is wrapped by ScrollViewer -> Grid -> StackPanel. In StackPanel I have input fields. when I trying to fill last of them on screen keyboard overlaying it and I cant see field and cant scroll to it. Is there any way to see it and to scroll to it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the popups on Windows 8 suffer from the same problem as they did on Windows Phone in that when you put a TextBox on one of them - it does not get pushed up together with all the other content as it does when it is not in a popup.

My solution to that would be to not use popup for input fields and instead go for a layout that you can manage yourself.

By default the app has a Frame control at its visual root. You can modify it for example by putting your own UserControl in there (I usually call it AppShell) which has the Frame used by all pages, you can have a layer for popups, log in screens, the extended splash screen etc.

To solve your problem you would need to put your charm's UI inside of such layer instead of in a popup. Then the build-in mechanism that pushes all the UI up when the on-screen keyboard would otherwise obstruct the view of your TextBox should just start working again.

*EDIT

A simpler solution might be to make sure your settings panel popup is parented in your visual tree - e.g. by adding it as a child element to a root grid of your app or page. It turns out that in that case its content does get pushed up when the OSK shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](http://socialeboladev.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/turn-any-usercontrol-into-a-pleasing-dialogflyout-in-windows-8/)

It's a popup wrapper (turns user controls into popups) that takes care of the keyboard appearing and adjusts the size of the popup (and thus the user control) accordingly.